# Android Application Screen problem

Tags: android, mobile, mobile-phones

I started doing things on android development and the screen isn't showing what it supposed to show. Is showing what i supposed to look like on the graphical layout but on the emulator i just shows "Android"

[image: Emulator]

[image: Graphical layout]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That screen shows as part of the emulator boot-up, so your emulator hasn't completed its boot process. The emulator sometimes can take upwards of 5 mins to boot. You have to wait until you see the unlock screen. If you enable snapshots that will greatly increase the emulator start time.

Comment: How do you make the emulator smaller. Is really big for my screen.

Comment: when you start it choose scale to real display size.

Comment: When i push run it brings it up. I don't see a scale

Comment: In Eclipse go to window-android sdk manager, and choose an avd to start. Then when you debug your project it will do it on the emulator you have started.

Answer (score 1):

It's still booting.  It can take a VERY long time for it to boot.  Make sure you didn't give too much memory to it.  I think I gave 9 MiB.